# searching for title of near future eco-science fiction

Tags: story-identification

Probably mid-eighties, the book's title may contain "wolf" or "coyote". Boy gets lost on father/son weekend trip to the environmentally off-limits wilderness - they're rich and can afford the necessary sealed self-contained vehicle, father may be in advertising. Similar to but not Theroux's 'Ozone'.

Some things I remember are the father being taken over and possibly controlled by insects (I believe this happened on a bus) and the son meeting a mythical Native American entity related to a wolf or coyote.